# How do i "subtract" a character from a string in c++

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a string variable with the value "bananas" in it. I want to subtract the last letter so the string becomes "banana". I am quite a newbie, so I dont even know how to tackle this.

Comment: [std::string::substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) and [std::string::pop_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/pop_back) might be helpful

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `pop_back()` function.

Try this code, it 'subtracts' the last character:

```
std::string str = "bananas";
str.pop_back();
```